# What is the hierarchy of JVM, JDK, JRE, JIT?

Tags: jvm, java, jit, java-6

Please explain in detail with regard to following points:

- Does JDK contain JRE?
- JDK converts .java to .class, then JVM understands the .class and converts in binary, then what is the actual need of JRE when OS can understand binary directly?
- What is openJDK?

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/) and you can get a clear image of JDK, JRE and JVM (Java HotSpot Client and Server VM). Don't read the words. Just look at the image-like table.

Comment: This is a very old question but talking about this today I came across it and I think the following links can help clarify the “hierarchy” or containment relationships. In summary: 1) JDK contains JRE and JVM 2) JRE contains JVM. // Sources-->
IBM: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/jvm-vs-jre-vs-jdk
JAVATPOINT: https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-jdk-jre-and-jvm

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I hope the above image will describe the answer

Source: [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/differentiate-jvm-jre-jdk-jit/)

Comment: Good picture, but JIT is not part of the JVM, but the **JRE**. Reference: *Although the JIT is not actually part of the JVM standard, it is, nonetheless, an essential component of Java* - [Oracle: Understanding JIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html)

Answer (score 5):

**Java Developer Kit(JDK)** contains tools needed to develop the Java programs, and **JRE** to run the programs. The tools include compiler (javac.exe), Java application launcher (java.exe), Appletviewer etc. Compiler converts java code into byte code. Java application launcher opens a JRE, loads the class, and invokes its main method. You need JDK, if at all you want to write your own programs, and to compile them. For running java programs, JRE is sufficient.

JRE is targeted for execution of Java files.
i.e. JRE = JVM + Java Packages Classes(like util, math, lang, awt,swing etc)+runtime libraries. JDK is mainly targeted for java development.

[**OpenJDK** (Open Java Development Kit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is a free and open source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE).

The [**Just-In-Time (JIT)**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.zos.70.doc%2Fdiag%2Funderstanding%2Fjit_overview.html) compiler is a component of the Java™ Runtime Environment that improves the performance of Java applications at run time.

You can get the entire conceptual diagram [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/).